# Use Xdebug with dockerized PHP project

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

Recently I've started to work on a new project that is dockerized and has Xdebug module. Also I've checked in container itself and 9000 port is listening and has Xdebug module version 2.9.8

I don't have any PHP or anything installed on my Ubuntu (host system).

In my PhpStorm I set my PHP interpreter manually:

[image]

Also set DBGp proxy like

[image]

Also created a server:

[image]

This is my etc/hosts:
and I call API in Postman with the following address: `api.vendet.local/api/v1/test`

UPDATED path mapping:
[image]

Still not break in any point. What is the problem and how can I do that?

Comment: I don't know anything about PHPStorm, but have you looked into path-mappings? Xdebug needs to know how to map the path of the error/break-causing-script inside the (in this case) docker to your local development directory structure. The IDE picks it up from there (is my limited understanding).

Answer (score 1):

> I've checked in container itself and 9000 port is listening

It is IDE that should be listening on port 9000, not the container.
#1: you don't need to use DBGp proxy.
#2: at PHP | Servers you have to enable "Use path mappings".

If I were you, I would delete all the configuration you made in PhpStorm (#1 & #2) and would start from the scratch.
First: make sure to configure XDebug properly in a container, see [Configure Xdebug running in a Docker container](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html#configuring-xdebug-docker). Pay attention to the value of `xdebug.client_host` described in the article.
Then: just run a simple [Zero-configuration debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/zero-configuration-debugging.html)

Comment: result of netstat -plnt of host and container is the exactly same and i try telnet 127.0.0.1 9000 and connection will be established . still not works . is there any way for check log to fix this. really bizzare
sorry a question xdebug is exists in php -m or php -v but not exists in phpinfo() . anyidea my friend?

Comment: Yea, sure. You can enable XDebug logging. See e.g. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#collect-xdebug-logs

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that as long as you are not using [`network_mode: "host"`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode) for the `php` container `localhost` / `127.0.0.1` for Xdebug running *within* the container is not the same as `localhost` on your Ubuntu host!

To be able to connect to Xdebug from PHPStorm you need to ensure the following:

- the debugger is listening on an IP reachable from the host: listening on `127.0.0.1` it would only be accessible from within the container itself. Connecting to `127.0.0.1:9000` on the host will be forwarded to the container, but to the virtual network interface of the container and not to the loopback device. To simply listen on all devices within the container specify `0.0.0.0` as address
- path mappings are enabled - since (most probably) the paths of the PHP files within the container are not identical with the paths to the same files on the host.

Comment: i tried telnet localhost 9000 from host and it will be connected . i added path mapping photo and still not works . could you please guide me more